# How to get logo about google assistant?

Tags: google-smart-home

I develop smart home actions for smart device, actions not published and lunch yet. but action is workable.

How about using Works with Google Assistant logo?
Can I use this logo for my device prototype DM?
or my action need to submit and lunched, then I can use
the logo?

Thank you.
BR,
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at [the canonical branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/branding-policies):

> You can let others know that your action “Works with the Google Assistant” using the badges seen here. You do not need pre-approval to use this badge provided your action is functional, compatible with the Google Assistant and your developer account is in good standing. Your action must be available at all times when using the badge.

> Please be sure that your use of the badge is consistent with the [Google Assistant Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/) and the branding guidelines below – otherwise we'll ask for modifications or cease your use of the badge.

The documentation includes further guidelines and links to download resources.